# MySQL JOIN ON, if column x is not null otherwise column y

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to join my products table, while grabing the orders.

I have a orders.product_id, which always have a value.

But the case is, if `orders.bproduct_id` is not null, we should go by this product id instead at the

```
->join('products')->on('products.id', '=', 'dealsite_orders.product_id')
```

(I am using Kohana Query Builder, but I accept an query answer)

How would I do this?

When I do:

```
JOIN ON COALESCE(orders.bproduct_id,product_id)
```

It does not return any rows. After investigating I found out, its because it takes column value from bproduct_id even if its 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `on` expression you are looking for something like this:

```
on products.id = coalesce(dealsite_orders.product_id, orders.product_id)
```

The `coalesce()` function returns the first value that is not null in the list of columns.  I'm not sure if you want to use this on the `dealsite` column or the `products` column.

Note that the use of `coalesce()` may prevent the use of an index.  If your tables are large, you might want to re-formulate the query to take advantage of your indexes.

Comment: `coalesce(dealsite_orders.bproduct_id, dealsite_orders.product_id)`, I think. That was what I was about to answer, when you posted a few seconds earlier. :)

Comment: This returns no rows at all ? I did:
JOIN `products` ON (`products`.`id` = COALESCE(orders.bproduct_id, orders.product_id)) 

If i switch places, it works fine, but then it will never use bproduct_id since product_id always return value.
bproduct_id is null by a 0 in the column.

Comment: @Karem If your 'null' is 0 instead of a real `null`, you can't use `coalesce`, and will have to use e.g. `JOIN products ON products.id = IF(orders.bproduct_id <> 0, orders.bproduct_id, orders.product_id)` instead.